# Data binding between template and controller within a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

myDirective is a **custom directive with an isolated scope**. I'm trying to do a **data binding between its template and its controller** for the ng-hide value. Could anyone tell my why the following code doesn't work? I also tried:

- `ng-hide="{{hidden}}"`
- `scope: {
      hidden: "="
   }`

I managed to do it in the link function through `scope.$apply('hidden=false');` but it sounds like a hack and I would prefer keeping all the logic in the directive controller.

**Edit:** This question has been updated following @Shuhei Kagawa answer.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude ng-hide="hidden"></div>',
        scope: true,
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.hidden = false;

            this.hide = function () {
                console.log("hide function called");
                $scope.hidden = true;
            }
        }
    }
});

myApp.directive('myButton', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^myDirective',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<button type="button" ng-transclude></button>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, myDirectiveCtrl) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                myDirectiveCtrl.hide();
            });

        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <my-directive>
        <my-button>Hide me!</my-button>
    </my-directive>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-hide requires a boolean value. So use `true`/`false` instead of `'true'`/`'false'`.

```
$scope.hidden = false;
// and
$scope.hidden = true;
```

Also, you don't need `scope: { hidden: "@" }` if you don't use my-directive's hidden attribute. Just use `scope: true` to create a new scope.

**EDIT**

When you handle DOM events directly instead of using `ng-click`, you need to call `scope.$apply()` to start [$digest cycle](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle). If you don't, Angular doesn't notice that `$scope` has changed.

```
element.bind('click', function () {
    scope.$apply(function() {
        myDirectiveCtrl.hide();
    });
});
```

Here is working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shuhei/ynmedmgb/4/).

Comment: I also tried with boolean before but it doesn't work. I updated a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5q21prt/2/).

Comment: I've added `scope.$apply()`. Please check out the edit.